# count specific word in line in bash

Tags: bash

i have variable such as "1,2,3,4"

i want to count of commas in this text in bash

any idea ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
echo "1,2,3" | tr -cd ',' | wc -c
```

Comment: Did not know of that tr -c usage, nice

Comment: actually tr -cd is doing this job well :)

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head using pure bash:

```
var="1,2,3,4"
temp=${var//[^,]/}
echo ${#temp}
```

Comment: Change the second line to: `temp=${var//[^,]/}` then it removes any non-comma.

Answer (score 1):

Isolate commas per line, count lines:

```
echo "$VAR"|grep -o ,|wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

A purely bash solution with no external programs:

```
$ X=1,2,3,4
$ count=$(( $(IFS=,; set -- $X; echo $#) - 1 ))
$ echo $count
3
$
```

Note: This destroys your positional parameters.

Comment: The eval and single quotes are unnecessary.

Comment: @Dennis: Ok. I got rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

Another pure Bash solution:

```
var="bbb,1,2,3,4,a,b,qwerty,,,"
saveIFS="$IFS"
IFS=','
var=($var)x
IFS="$saveIFS"
echo $((${#var[@]} - 1))
```

will output "10" with the string shown.

Comment: Doesn't work with `var="1,2,3"` (seems to work only if there's a trailing comma).

Comment: @Alok: Thanks for pointing that out. It's now fixed. I like **SiegeX's** version better, though.

Answer (score 0):

very simply with awk

```
$ echo 1,2,3,4 | awk -F"," '{print NF-1}'
3
```

with just the shell

```
$ s="1,2,3,4"
$ IFS=","
$ set -- $s
$ echo $(($#-1))
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '1,2,3' | grep -o ',' | wc -l
```